# Advantage of using LEA with simple addresses

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Take for example the following two instructions:

```
LEA  rax, [label]
MOV  rax, label
```

Is there any actual advantage to using the `LEA` instruction instead of the `MOV` instruction when it is only a simple address such as this? For instance, might it be faster or a smaller instruction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have `rip` relative addressing enabled by default (e.g. for nasm, `default rel`). In that case the `lea` uses that and the `mov` uses absolute. The `lea` will indeed be shorter machine code because it uses 32 bit displacement as opposed to a 64 bit immediate. If you don't use `rip` relative, the `lea` can only address in the low 32 bits. Also note that in position independent code the absolute `mov` is not allowed.

Comment: @Jester: Huh, that's surprising.  NASM does use `mov rax, imm64`.  YASM uses `mov rax, imm32` (7 bytes), I guess because it knows the default code model is "small", so all static addresses fit in a 32-bit zero or sign-extended immediate.  (i.e. **5-byte `mov eax, label` works in non-PIC code**, but YASM doesn't optimize away useless REX prefixes for you in general, like with `mov rax, 2`.)  I was expecting NASM to optimize to `mov eax, imm32` like it usually does for constants that fit, but I guess it's only a link-time constant, not assemble-time.

Comment: RIP-relative LEA can only execute on port 1 on Intel Skylake, vs. any port for `mov`-immediate.  (http://agner.org/optimize/).  It's not a perf win unless you're avoiding a 64-bit immediate.  But it's by far the best way to make position-independent code.